# Segmentation Fault on my while loop

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I am trying to count the number of lines and characters whatever they may be in a file that I specify from argv. But I get a segmentation fault when I hit the while loop for some reason. The program runs fine without the while loop, though it only goes through once.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if(argc != 2) {
            return 0;
    }


    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    int lines = 0;
    int chs = 0;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    //Segmentation Fault happens here on the while loop
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
            if(c == '\n') {
                    lines += 1;
            }
            else {
                    chs += 1;
            }

    }

    printf("Charaters: %d\n", chs);
    printf("lines: %d\n", lines);


    if(fp){
            fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't checked if `fopen()` succeeded (`fp != NULL`) before entering the loop.  Passing a `NULL` pointer to `fgetc()` gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: `fgetc` returns an `int` intentionally.

Comment: The problem was i was opening a null file. So i should have checked if it was null first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your code needs to be follow Idiomatic C more closely.
- You should validate `fopen` immediately, instead of after you've already attempted to use `fp`.
- `fgetc` returns `int`, not `char`. This is because it needs to return side-channel information about the status of the stream (i.e. `EOF`), this information cannot be represented by `char`, but you can safely cast the `int` value to `char` if the value is not `EOF`.
- Your code treats `\r` as a regular character when it is commonplace for `\r\n` to represent a line-break (not just a solitary `\n`), you might want to consider how you handle different character classes.
- Your program does not handle non-trivial encodings (i.e. it will only correctly handle files in your system's native encoding, presumably ASCII). You should use a Unicode library to correctly read individual characters from a file: for example your program will treat a surrogate-pair in UTF-8 as two characters instead of 1, and would incorrectly count UTF-16 files.

Better:

```
FILE* fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
if( !fp ) {
    printf( "Could not open file \"%s\" for reading.\r\n", argv[1] );
    return 1;
}

int lines = 0;
int chars = 0;

int nc;
while( ( nc = fgetc( fp ) ) != EOF ) {

    char c = (char)nc;

    if     ( c == '\n' ) lines++;
    else if( c != '\r' ) chars++;
}

printf( "Characters: %d\r\nLines: %d\r\n", chars, lines );

fclose( fp );

return 0;
```